# Why does the first '<br>' show?

Tags: javascript, browser, adobe-captivate

I am trying to display strings in Adobe Captivate 9 text captions with JavaScript. I'm using a non-responsive project, and the below code always shows the first "br" tag for newline. If I'm to remove the "br" tags in `userResults` then the "br" tag in `topTenUsers` will be seen.

However, in a responsive project, the same code does not show any of the "br" tags.

Code:

```
    var userResults = 'You placed at rank ' + myRank + ' with a score of ' + myScore + '<br>' + '<br>';
    var topTenUsers = 'The top ' + numPlayers + ' users are: <br>';
    var topTenMsg = userResults + ' ' + topTenMsg;

    window.cpAPIInterface.setVariableValue(topTenVarName, topTenMsg);
```

What is the cause of this difference and how could it be avoided?

Comment: variables do not match in your code sample...

Comment: I've added the line which concatenates the two variables. I've kept the code shown as simple as possible, as the real code is speaking with servers. The problem only stems from the first two lines.

Answer (score 0):

Try a self-closing `br`.

```
var userResults = 'You placed at rank ' + myRank + ' with a score of ' + myScore + '<br />' + '<br />'
```

Comment: I have already tried cloding the "br" tag, but then it simply displays the first self-closing "br" tag.